# Is it appropriate to include time lagged feature in traditional (non-time series) ML approach?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

I have done some searching and haven't been able to come up with a conclusive answer to this question. Let's say I have several features that do not involve time such as: school district, zip code, age, reading level, and I am trying to predict the percentage of tests that a student will pass during 30-day windows. Let's say we also only have data for 90 days, so there would only be two lagged features (% of tests passed in first 30 days, % of tests passed in second 30 days).

Is it appropriate to use a lagged feature in combination with those static features to predict the total percentage of tests passed and/or tests passed at 90 days? I read a paper where they used an ensemble of a time-series model and a static model to make predictions on such data, but it seems problematic to build a time-series model if there are only two time periods for each student. It also seems like if the time features were included in a traditional ML model there might be some issues with iid assumption? Thanks for your time, happy to provide any other information necessary. Coming up empty even after searching the literature and here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to use a lagged feature in combination with those
>   static features to predict the total percentage of tests passed and/or
>   tests passed at 90 days?

Yes, and it's commonly used (at least in the industry). Not all time series problems are solved via traditional time-series methods.

> It also seems like if the time features were included in a traditional
>   ML model there might be some issues with iid assumption?

iid assumption concerns the independence of different samples. Say, you're predicting $x_t$ with features $x_{t-1}$ and some other static ones. And, let another training sample $x_{t-1}$ with features $x_{t-2}$ and corresponding static ones. Surely, the training samples are not iid, but even so this type of approach is commonly used as well. A typical example would be LSTM networks.

Comment: Any chance there is some literature you're familiar with that says this?